# How can I attach a file using Wordpress custom fields / meta boxes?

Tags: wordpress, upload, custom-fields

I am using Wordpress's [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function to add customized meta fields to the Add New Post page, [like this](http://wefunction.com/2008/10/tutorial-creating-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/). I want one of these fields to allow the user to upload a file, so that a single image, pdf, audio file, or video can be associated with the post.

The closest example I've seen is this one (link removed*). Unfortunately it does not suit my needs, as I want my file to be processed by Wordpress's Media Uploader - so it should appear in the Media Library afterwards, and thumbnails should be generated according to the Media settings.

I think ideally there would be a way to tap into Wordpress's existing Add Media dialog, and simply output the URL of the uploaded file into a text box, but I don't see how to do that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682926/how-would-you-recommend-adding-an-image-as-a-custom-field-in-wordpress) is similar, but the answers are a little clunky - I would like to keep this super simple for my end users.

How can I accomplish this? Please do not recommend plugins such as Flutter or Magic Fields - I have tried these and they do not suit my purposes (I want the images to be processed by Wordpress's Media Uploader). I am using Wordpress 3.0-alpha.

(*=link removed due to report of malware; it is in the archive, but at own risk)

Comment: Hello

@shipshape, I would be very interested in your work. If possible, can you post, at least, un link to an archive to download your code. It would be nice for all the people who are looking for an answer on this topic.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured this out for myself and got it working just as I wanted, and thought I would post an update for anyone who finds this question and is curious.

I did not use any plugins, but wrote a custom function to handle file uploads for my theme. I used built-in Wordpress functions such as  save_custom_postdata(), wp_handle_upload(), wp_insert_attachment(), wp_generate_attachment_metadata() and wp_update_attachment_metadata().

I also had to use add_action('admin_head'...) to add some JavaScript which adds "multipart/form-data" to the form tag on the Edit Post page, to allow file uploads.

I would post my code, but it is very long and specific to my project.

Comment: It's unfortunate you won't post at least some of the more relevant bits of your code. Consider giving back to the community by taking half an hour out of your life to excerpt some of your solution.

Comment: Totally agree with @Tom Auger, would be nice to see the code even if it is specific, to get an overall idea on how to handle files in meta boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You needn't use JavaScript to edit the form. This is possible to do using the post_edit_form_tag function like so:

```
add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag' , 'post_edit_form_tag' );

function post_edit_form_tag( ) {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```

More details (including an example) are available at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_edit_form_tag.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Image Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-widget/) - a well made widget that does what you want, but as a widget. Maybe you can convert it to work on your Add new post page.

Another plugin you can try is [Pods CMS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/). Might be overkill but when you do fileuploads with this, they are automaticly added to the media library.

Answer (score 0):

This [WordPress Meta Box PHP Helper class](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) might help you when working with WordPress Meta Boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nkmimagefield/
Apparently it doesn't support custom post types but a little hacking should do. It already does the hard work of interfacing with the media editor.